# How can I filter and show an array with React?

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, filtering

I'm trying to filter some companies array -that is being shown in a table- using multiple checkboxes. These checkboxes returns an array of strings with some status. For example: `['accepted', 'pending', 'declined'];`.
The problem is that while the checkboxes returns the status OK, I cannot manage to filter the companies array with the checkboxes data.

Here is my main code:

```
function App() {

  const [filters, setFilters] = useState([]);
  const [companies, setCompanies] = useState([
    { id: 1, status: "accepted", name: "001", date: "01/01/2022" },
    { id: 2, status: "accepted", name: "001", date: "01/01/2022" },
    { id: 8, status: "accepted", name: "001", date: "10/04/2022" },
  ]);

  //HERE I TRY TO FILTER MY COMPANIES ARRAY WITH THE SELECTED CHECKBOXES
  const showFilteredCompanies = (filters) => {
    return [...companies].filter((company) => {
      return filters.includes(company.status);
    });
  }


  //Inside data I have my array of selected status like this: ['accepted', 'pending', 'declined']

  const handleFilters = (data) => {
    
    let newFilters = {...filters};
    newFilters = data;
    setFilters(newFilters);

    // THIS CONSOLE.LOG SHOWS THE FILTERED ARRAY OF COMPANIES JUST FINE
    console.log(showFilteredCompanies(newFilters));

    const filtered = showFilteredCompanies(newFilters);

    //BUT WHEN I TRY TO SAVE MY COMPANIES FILTERED ARRAY IN MY STATE THE FILTERING DOESN'T WORK AS IT SHOULD
    console.log(filtered);
    setCompanies(filtered);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">

      <Checkbox 
        handleFilters={data => handleFilters(data)}
      />

      {/* companies list */}
      <div>
        {companies.length ? 
          (
            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>Estado</th>
                  <th>nombre</th>
                  <th>Fecha</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {companies.map((company, i) => (
                    <tr key={i}>
                      <td>{company.id}</td>
                      <td>{company.status}</td>
                      <td>{company.name}</td>
                      <td>{company.date}</td>
                    </tr>
                  )
                )}
              </tbody>
            </table>   
          ) : (
            <h2>No hay compañías para mostrar</h2>
          )
        }
      </div>

      {/* list length */}
      <div>
          <h3>Cantidad de compañías: {companies.length}</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I was expecting to filter my companies array with all the strings of my checkboxes data array to show only the companies.status that matches the selected status of the checkboxes

Comment: You should not be setting filtered companies as state. The checkboxes are state because they are influenced by user actions. The filtered companies are a derived product of this state. Just filter on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the filtering of companies might not need to be another state, and could possibly be chained with `map()` in the output for simplicity.

Not sure if it would work without testing in the use case, but assuming that `filters` are updated just fine as posted, perhaps try omit `showFilteredCompanies` and `setCompanies` in `handleFilters`, and add in the output:

```
{ /* companies list with filter before map */ }
<div>
  {companies.length ? (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Estado</th>
          <th>nombre</th>
          <th>Fecha</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {companies
          .filter((company) =>
            filters.length > 0 ? filters.includes(company.status) : true
          )
          .map((company, i) => (
            <tr key={i}>
              <td>{company.id}</td>
              <td>{company.status}</td>
              <td>{company.name}</td>
              <td>{company.date}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  ) : (
    <h2>No hay compañías para mostrar</h2>
  )}
</div>
```